# [LINUX]usuario en grupo root no tiene permisos de escritura pese a que el grupo root si lo tiene otorgado

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo una carpeta cuyo owner y grupo son '***root***', tiene asignados permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución tanto para owner como para el grupo, ahora he añadido un usuario al grupo 'root' con:

`sudo usermod -a -G root usuario`

Compruebo que se ha añadido en */etc/group* y efectivamente ahi está:

`root:x:0:usuario`

Sin embargo, cuando intento hacer cualquier cosa que requiere escritura en la carpeta antes mencionada, me da error de permisos insuficientes de escritura.

¿Faltaria algún paso más para que el usuario pueda usar los permisos del grupo ***root***?

Un saludo.

---

**Edición**

El comando `ls -1` me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 sep 22 13:57 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 feb 9 2021 etc
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 feb 9 2021 games
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 feb 9 2021 include
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root 4096 sep 22 13:57 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 ago 25 00:30 man -> share/man
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 feb 9 2021 sbin
drwxrwxr-x 7 root root 4096 feb 9 2021 share 
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 feb 9 2021 src
```

Comment: cierra sesión y vuélvela a abrir

Comment: Acabo de probar lo que me has dicho @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' pero igualmente sigue denegandome la escritura

Comment: No es solo cerrar una sesión. En mi experiencia, hay que cerrar _todas_ las sesiones del usuario en el equipo para que al abrir una nueva sesión, funcione.

Comment: Gracias @eftshift0, tras reiniciar por completo el equipo, parece funcionar, era simplemente este el problema, no pude probarlo antes porque tenia varias cosas en marcha que no podía apagar, un saludo.

Comment: Pónganlo como respuesta.

Comment: Hace mucho que no hago una pregunta, ¿no veo la opción para marcar un comentario como respuesta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que tenga efecto ese cambio, hay que cerrar *todas* las sesiones del usuario abiertas en el equipo.